# What does groupon mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I googled it but couldn't find any results.

In the next 12 months, Mehta came up with ideas for around 20 products— which included groupon for food and a social network for lawyers — but none clicked. “The reason to start a company should never be to start a company. The reason to start a company should be to solve a problem that you truly, truly care about,” Mehta said at a Y Combinator talk in 2014

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jenniferwang/2020/06/17/instacart-founder-apoorva-mehta-becomes-a-billionaire/#5708c3277e02

Comment: Did you really use Google? If you type 'groupon' or 'Groupon' into Google, you are rapidly led to the solution of your problem.

Comment: I agree, first hit!

Comment: I always recommend learners to google English words using Google.com (USA) or Google.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Groupon](https://www.groupon.com/) is a proper noun name for an actual business entity.